# Creating Custom Expresion for Field Calculations and the Model Builder

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler, expression

I am currently exploring Model Builder and I have some trouble setting a custom expression up for certain vector fields of a layer feature collection (points, line and polygons). This is the kind of expression I have in mind:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN "COLUMN" is NOT NULL THEN string_to_array(string_to_array( "COLUMN" ,'"')[7]
  ELSE NULL
END
```

"Column" is of-course all the name of the Column(s) that is (are) selected and are supposed to go through this expression process. So how do I do this?

Comment: Did you investigate the geoalgorithms `"Execute SQL"` or `"Refactor fields"` in the Model Builder?

Comment: Refactor fields is what I used originally. But I wanted to create "a common expression" that could be replicated on specific columns. Without specifying the column name. I am leaving this question open for now, even though for my situation this is kind of solved of refactored.